# How to generate pom file for existing eclipse plugin project?

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, pom.xml

I didn't really use maven so it may be noob question.

I have Eclipse plugin project and before I deploy it, I need to generate a pom file. The regular pom file is designed for java projects and if I try to generate from them I lose my plugin dependencies. Is there a way for maven to include them,too ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Maven works for Eclipse plugin projects as well.  Are you saying that you created a standard Eclipse plugin project and now want to convert it to a Maven structured project?

Comment: Yes,with plugin  dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting a standard Eclipse plugin project to a Maven structured project is not as simple as generating a pom file.  The project needs to be in the same directory structure that Maven expects.

If you want to build Eclipse plugins as Maven projects take a look at Tycho (http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/).